# Proving the inexistence of the sum of the harmonic series $\frac{1}{n}$ using the ratio test

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I try to [prove](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum_%28n%3D0%29%5Einfty%201%2Fn) that the sum $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac1n$ diverges. I want to use the ratio test on the series $\frac1n$.

Here I do

\begin{equation}
    \lim_{n\longrightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n+1}\frac{n}{1}= \lim_{n\longrightarrow\infty}\frac{n}{n+1}
\end{equation}

But I cannot get any further. Is there a better test than this, or can this be solved, if so, how?

Thanks

Comment: The limit is $1$ so ratio test is inconclusive. Also the series is $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty a_n$ not just $a_n = 1/n$ which is a sequence.

Comment: When the result of the ratio is $1$ you can say nothing about the series

Comment: I edited the question.

Comment: Regardless, this is a very well-known problem. This website should have countless answers on how to show this.

Comment: I checked, cannot find it.

Comment: See Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics). The most common proof I see is the integral test.

Comment: Refer also to which generalize the method presented in the given answer https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test

Comment: @AdamRubinson what do you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac1n$ obviously diverges, since $\frac{1}{0}$ is part of the sum. But usually for harmonic series (so there's no $\frac{1}{0}$ as the first element in the series) is defined as $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^k}$, where in your case $k=1$. To prove this we can use [integral test for covergence of series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20the%20integral%20test,as%20the%20Maclaurin%E2%80%93Cauchy%20test.).

Let's define function $f(x)=\frac1x$. Now let's check the following:
$$\int_{1}^{+\infty}{f(x)dx}=\int_{1}^{+\infty}{\frac{1}{x}dx}=\ln{x} \Bigg{|}^{+\infty}_{1}=\ln({+\infty})-\ln1=\ln({+\infty})$$
Which is obviously divergent, therefore $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}$ is also divergent.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with the ratio test in this case is that the limit of $\frac{n}{n+1}$ as $n$ goes to infinity is 1, and so the test is inconclusive. A straightforward way to see that this series diverges is to do the following:

Round the denominator of $\frac{1}{n}$ to the smallest power of 2 larger than $n$, i.e the sum $$1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + 1/4 + 1/5+ 1/6+ 1/7+ 1/8 + \cdots$$ becomes $$1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/4 + 1/8 +  1/8 + 1/8 + 1/8 + \cdots .$$
This second sum is clearly smaller than our original sum, as the denominator is larger in each term. So if we show that the second sum diverges, then the first sum will also diverge as it is larger than the second sum, and the second sum goes to infinity (this is just like the comparison test). To show the second sum diverges, we group together all of the terms with the same denomiator and get
$$1 + 1/2 + 2/4 + 4/8 + \cdots = 1 + 1/2 + 1/2 + 1/2 + \cdots$$
so we are adding infinitely many halves, so this series will diverge, and hence our original series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n}$ diverges.

Answer (score 0):

The series starts at $n=1$, as $\frac10$ is not defined. The ratio test is inconclusive, but you can easily prove it diverges using the integral test.